# Can YouTube videos count as non-commercial and/or educational for the purpose of fair use?

Tags: united-states, copyright, fair-use, youtube

One of the factors courts consider when determining when use of copyrighted material falls under fair use is whether the use is for “[nonprofit educational purposes](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/107)”.

Now, some claim or assume that educational YouTube videos count as “educational” for this purpose, and that channels that aren’t monetized are non-commercial/non-profit. But I’ve seen others claim that “educational” in fair-use law only applies to professional educators in an academic environment (teachers screening a documentary in class, etc.), and thus nothing on YouTube counts as “educational” for fair use; and that because YT is a for-profit commercial entity, nothing posted to it is ever “non-commercial”/“non-profit” in the eyes of fair use, regardless of a channel’s monetization status.

Which view is correct? I’ve tried Googling, but I can’t find any clear answers. (The closest I’ve found is [this Law SE post](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/66604/does-fair-use-of-copyright-apply-to-educational-youtube-channels), but aside from the title, the actual question is completely different and unrelated to mine.)

Comment: FWIW, "nonprofit educational purposes" while it is one factor in fair use, is routinely exaggerated in importance relative to other factors by non-lawyers. Copyright is a property law concept and not an unjust enrichment concept, even though perhaps it shouldn't be.