Can I use clips of another show I created in my own feature film?
The opening scene of my film is of a out-of-work TV writer, explaining his background to two TV network commissioners, where he plays a brief clip (2 seconds) of a sitcom pilot that he created. The shot appears on a laptop.
I created the sitcom pilot (14 years ago) and own the copyright for it. The copyright for my film is also completely owned by me.
My question is, do I need to get the sign off from the actors from the sitcom pilot, in order to use this clip in my film?
I look forward to any insights you have.


https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/length-of-movie-clip-for-fair-use

If you own the copyright, you can license it to yourself for free.
The only time that actors need to be considered if if the actors in your original work which you are used in the new film have contract rights to be paid if that happens in their contracts with you.
Customarily, very minor actors and actors on short projects don't get royalties and just get paid for their work, but major actors often have royalties as part of their package and their rights to royalties under the contracts for the original work, if any, must be considered and addressed.

Actors do not own copyright
The makers (and copyright owners) of a cinematographic film are the producer(s), director(s), and screenwriter(s). These are the only people who matter for copyright law.
However, you will need to check the contracts with the actors to see if they have any contractural rights on redisplay. You also cannot present the actors in a way that is defamatory, or that infringes any rights of publicity they may have.

Usually, the copyright is owned by a single project company that makes that film and nothing else, and the producers, directors, and screenwriters give up their copyright as work for hire in exchange for an ownership interest or contractual royalty rights.

@ohwilleke sure - but I get the feeling what the OP is asking about isn’t that big a production. It seems home made.
